# KDB show table, not cumulative results

Tags: kdb

In the tutorial on kdb: 
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/1_Q_Shock_and_Awe/
It deals with a FIFO allocation

The tutorial calls for the user to  assign the lists respectively:

```
q)buys:2 1 4 3 5 4f
q)sell:12f
```

The tutorial show the answer as this:

```
q)deltas each deltas sums[sells] &\: sums[buys]
2 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 3 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
```

however when i run the smae line in q, I get the following.

```
q)deltas each deltas sums[sells] &\: sums[buys]
2 1 4 3 2 0f
q)
```

i understand the results, however i want to display them in a table graphically as is is show in the tutorial.I want to see the table, spanned over four rows, as opposed the the cumulative answer in one line.

Comment: If you just want that resultant vector to look like a matrix you can multiply it by an identity matrix to mimic the behaviour of when there is more than one sell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial has sells defined differently:

```
q)buys:2 1 4 3 5 4f
q)sells:2 4 3 2
q)deltas sums[sells] &\: sums[buys]
2 2 2 2 2 2
0 1 4 4 4 4
0 0 1 3 3 3
0 0 0 1 2 2
q)deltas each deltas sums[sells] &\: sums[buys]
2 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 3 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: I think the OPs point is that (s)he wants to be able to apply the logic with only a single sell and still have the result shown as a matrix. Unless I'm reading it wrong